# Multivariable Factor Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

By my previous questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483395/factoring-a-polynomial-multivariable/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483376/how-is-fa-b-c-symmetric?) I have been inspired to ask about the factor theorem; the multivariable case of it.

So take $f(a, b, c) = (a-b)^3 + (b-c)^3 + (c-a)^3$

$f(a, a, c) = f(b, b, c) = f(a, c, c) = f(a, b, a) = f(a, b, b)$ these give factors: $(b - a), (a - b), (b - c), (c - a), (c - b)$, so which ones am I supposed to use?

Comment: You mean $(c-a)$ instead of $(b-a)$.

Comment: This type of theorem is possible if you can extract as many factors as the total degree. This often happens for determinants, eg: the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: Use all factors which are distinct. Note that factors which differ only by multiplication with a unit (in this case all real numbers are units) are not distinct. As it is a cubic, you shouldn't get more than three such factors.

Comment: @Macavity, yes, but which distinct ones should I use? $(b-c)(b-a)(c-a)$ is distinct but it wont end up giving the right answer.

Comment: Of course it will give the right answer. All you need is a unit (in this case $-3$) in front. That scalar can always be found by checking any one coefficient, or testing for some non-zero value of $f$.

Comment: @Macavity, huh. Very nice; is there any explanation for why we need distinct factors? (But overall, it works very good then!)