# According to what rigorous definition of "polynomial" is $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k D^k$ a polynomial, where $D$ is the derivative operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, factoring

Let $Df$ be the derivative of $f\in C^{\infty}$.
\begin{align}
D^k\colon C^{\infty}&\to C^{\infty}\\
f&\mapsto f^{(k)}=\begin{cases}f&\text{ if }k=0\\
Df^{(k-1)}&\text{ if }1\leq k
\end{cases}
\end{align}
I was told that if $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbf{C}^{n+1}$, $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k D^k$ is a polynomial and can thus be factorized. That is, there is a $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in\mathbf{C}^n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k D^k = a_n \prod_{i=1}^{n}(D^1 - b_iD^0).
\end{equation}

> According to what **rigorous** definition of "polynomial" is that true and where can I find more information?

Unfortunately, I didn't find the Wikipedia article helpful and I'm not sure if the definition as sequences in some ring is what I'm looking for, as I have no background in abstract algebra.

Comment: $\Bbb{C}[D]$ (the polynomials in $D$) is an algebra whose elements are linear maps $C^\infty\to C^\infty$ and $D^2$ is the composition $D\circ D$. As an algebra it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for the comment. Could you please name a book (or some other reference) that gives more information, e.g. how and for what $A$ the symbol $\mathbb C[A]$ is defined?

Comment: Moreover, over $\Bbb C$, if $\Phi(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is an entire fuction of exponential growth, then the operator $$\Phi(D)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n D^n:H(\Bbb C)\to H(\Bbb C): f(z)\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n f^{(n)}(z)$$ is well defined and it is a continuopus operator. See for ecxmaple, Complex Analysis of Berenstein&Gay. This operator is called  Infinite Order Differential Operator.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thank you very much, as I already said, I have no background in abstract algebra, so I'm very happy about the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know from school, polynomial functions can be factorized and that result can be used to show that any polynomial (with complex coefficients) can be factorized.

To make this precise, let's introduce some notation: For all $n\in\mathbf{N}_0$, let's define
\begin{align}
\tau_n\colon\mathbf{C}&\to\mathbf{C}\\
x&\mapsto x^n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n=0\\
x^{n-1}\cdot x&\text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{equation}
V:=\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\tau_n:a_n=0\text{ for all almost all }n\right\}
\end{equation}
is the set of all polynomial functions (it's a vector space and $\{\tau_n:n\in\mathbf{N}_0\}$ is a basis).
Using the fundamental theorem of algebra and the division algorithm (Theorem 17.6 in [1] or theorem 3.46 in [2]), one can show that any polynomial function can be factorized - this means that there is $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in\mathbf{C}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\tau_k = a_n \prod_{i=1}^{n}\tau_1 - b_i\tau_0.
\end{equation}
([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850784/statement-about-divisors-of-polynomials-and-their-roots) are more details.)

To prove
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k = a_n \prod_{i=1}^{n}X^1 - b_iX^0,
\end{equation}
we can introduce the linear map
\begin{align}
\phi\colon V&\to\mathbf{C}[X]\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k\tau_k&\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kX^k
\end{align}
You can easily prove that for all $A,B\in V$, $\phi(A\cdot B)=\phi(A)\cdot\phi(B)$ and therefore
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k=\phi\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\tau_k\right)=\phi\left(a_n \prod_{i=1}^{n}\tau_1-b_i\tau_0\right)\\=a_n\prod_{i=1}^{n}\phi\left(\tau_1 - b_i\tau_0\right)=a_n \prod_{i=1}^{n}X^1 - b_iX^0
\end{align}

**One further comment**: Let $R$ be a ring.
\begin{equation}
R[X]:=\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nX^n:a_n=0\text{ for all almost all }n\right\}
\end{equation}
If nothing is known about $X$, we have to **define**
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nX^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nX^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n+b_n)X^n
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nX^n\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nX^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k+l=n}a_kb_l\right)X^n
\end{equation}
to make $R[X]$ a ring. But if $A$ is an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra) and $X\in A$, you can define $X^0:=1\in A$ and $X^{n+1}:=X^n\cdot X$ and **prove** $(1)$ and $(2)$.

> In the case of my question, $R=\mathbf{C}$, $A=L\left(C^{\infty},C^{\infty}\right)$ is the set of linear maps from $C^{\infty}$ to $C^{\infty}$, $X=D$ and $\sum_{k=0}^na_kD^k\in\mathbf{C}[D]$.

[1] Thomas W. Judson. *Abstract Algebra*. 2019.

[2] Joseph J. Rotman. *A first course in abstract algebra*. 3rd edition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P = \sum_k a_k X^k \in \mathbb{C}[X]$. The sum $P(D) := \sum_k a_k D^k$ is an endomorphism of the vector space $C^{\infty}$ (see the theory of endomorphism polynomials).

One has, when $E$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{K}$, $R, Q \in \mathbb{K}[X]$ are polynomials and $u$ an endomorphism, that: $R(u) \circ Q(u) = (RQ)(u)$.

Over $\mathbb{C}$, the fundamental theorem of algebra gievs us the existence of coefficients $b_1, \dots, b_n$ such that $P = a_n \prod (X - b_k)$.

Thus: $P(D) = a_n \prod \left( (X - b_k)(D) \right) = a_n \prod \left( D - b_k Id_{C^{\infty}} \right)$.

Comment: Thank you :) Could you please add a reference for these results? I find it surprisingly difficult to find one by searching on google.

Comment: Do you know what the polynomial of an endomorphism is?

Comment: I know about the charasteric polynomial of an endomorphism, but that's not what you mean, is it?

Comment: I do realize that an expression like $\sum_{k=0}^n a_0 X^k$ makes sense for an arbitrary endomorphism (linear map) $X\colon V\to V$, if we set $X^0:=\text{id}$ and $X^{n+1}:=X^n\circ X$ (if that is what you mean).

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Starting from this definition, you'll easily show the property with the product. What else do you need to understand after?

Comment: I think I understand now. My problem was that I had a hard time finding a definition of $R[X]$. I read the wikipedia article and downloaded five of the books on abstract algebra suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study) and all I found was $R[X]:=\{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kX^k:\text{there is }N\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }a_k=0\text{ for }N\leq k\}$, where nothing was said about $X$. I found that very unsatisfying. Then I downloaded a sixth book and finally I found a more precise definition:

Comment: $R[X]:=\{a\colon\mathbb{N}_0\to R:a_k=0\text{ if }N\leq k\}$, and $X:=(0,1,0,0,...)$. I was happy about that, but then someone told me that $R[X]$ is defined by a universal property, just like the tensor product. I guess this means that there are different ways to define $R[X]$ and therefore also different ways to think about the factorisation of polynomials. I would be very happy to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: Yeah, there are different ways to formally define $\mathbb{R}[X]$. But that's not what is important here. Any way we use to define polynomials, they behave as we expect (in terms of products, sums, etc.). When you master polynomials and endomorphisms, you define endomorphisms polynomials as you did before. The properties they verify aren't hard to prove.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for the answer. I realized that it's not so import what $R[X]$ is (where $R$ is a ring). What I really needed to know was only how to derive the factorization of complex polynomial functions using the fundamental theorem of algebra and polynomial division and how to generalize this result to all complex polynomials (that's what you showed me for the special case of endomorphisms) :)

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial ring $\mathbb C[X]$ satisfies the following universal property: If $\iota:\mathbb C\longrightarrow S$ is a commutative ring extension of $\mathbb C$ (so $S$ is commutative and $\iota$ is an injective ring homomorphism) and $s\in S$, then there is exactly one homomorphism $e:\mathbb C[X]\longrightarrow S$ such that $e(X)=s$ and $e(z)=\iota(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. We call $e$ an evaluation homomorphism, since it evaluates each polynomial at $s$ by plugging in $s$ for $X$. You can find this property on Wikipedia, or really any decent book on abstract algebra. Look for universal property of polynomial rings.

Now here the ring $S$ is the ring of differential operators of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\mathrm D^k$, and we have $\iota:z\mapsto z\mathrm D^0$. Also, we choose $s=\mathrm D$. We notice that the operator $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\mathrm D^k$ is exactly the image of the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k$ under the evaluation homomorphism. And since the polynomial can be factored, and homomorphisms are multiplicative, its image can be factored in exactly the same way.

Comment: Great answer! I have one problem though: Since the domain of $e$ is $\mathbb{C}[X]$, I don't understand the equation $e(z)=\iota(z)$ - is that a typo?

Comment: In this context we consider $\mathbb C\subset\mathbb C[X]$. Though we could make it even more explicit by defining the natural inclusion $i:\mathbb C\longrightarrow\mathbb C[X]$ and saying $e\circ i(z)=\iota(z)$, if you prefer.

Comment: Does this mean that there are different definitions of $R[X]$, just like there are different definitions of $V\otimes W$?

Comment: Yes, there are. Or more specifically, there is a universal definition (a polynomial ring over $R$ is a commutative ring extension with the universal property described above), and then there are multiple ways to construct ring extensions which have this property. But they're all naturally isomorphic, so it really doesn't matter which one we pick, as long as we can point to one of them and say: there, at least one exists. The definition via sequences in $R$ is the most known one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm happy that you explicitly mentioned that the definition via sequences in $R$ is just one possible way.

Comment: I am familiar with the universal properties of cartesian product, tensor product and tangent space, so I think I understand :)