# Factorisation thm for 2 variables plynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

The factorisation thm for polynomial in one variable $p \in F[x]$ says that if $p(\alpha)=0$,
then there is $r \in \mathbb{N} $  s.t $p(x)=(x-\alpha)^rh(x)$ where $h(\alpha)\neq0$.
Is there is similiar thm for polynomial in 2(or n) variables? i.e for polynomials in $F[x,y]$?

Comment: Related: [Does there exist a formal statement of the Multivariable Factor Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222592/does-there-exist-a-formal-statement-of-the-multivariable-factor-theorem).

Comment: It is. thank you